# Lenovo Battery Capacity reduced to under 20%

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop, battery-life

I have a 2 years old lenovo Z51-70 laptop (Windows 10). Recently I started experiencing faster battery drainage.

Using windows tool powercfg, I generated battery and energy reports.

[image]

[image]

It looks likes that the battery capacity has decreased to 18%.

Now, I have gone through many battery saving options and tips, applied them but didn't see any significant changes.

My question is:

1. How to resolve errors (highlighted in red) specified by energy report. Searching most of them on google didn't yield much results.
2. Should I change my battery instead? I am out of warranty period and while this looks like gradual wear of battery, is it normal for Li - batteries to degrade this much within 2 years. To get a picture, my PC initially worked for 4hrs unplugged which is now reduced to 45 min.

Personally, I would like to stretch current battery as much possible.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solution = Get a new battery

Comment: So is 2 years normal for battery life

Comment: At the end of the day what is normal for a battery means little to your specific battery. If average battery life is 100 years and yours is 2 then you would still need to replace it =)

Answer (score 2):

Lenovo batteries typically perform approximately **three** years but individual usage patterns can affect longevity. [Lenovo](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/hf004122) like [many others](https://www.engadget.com/2006/10/19/sony-battery-recall-approaches-10-million-costs-mounting/) had a battery recall but your Z51 **wasn't** recalled and it seems your experience isn't extraordinary.

You're well served to contact [Lenovo Tech Support](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/contactnow) to determine if your battery is warrantied, from the US 877 453 6686 or other [CallYou](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/contactus/callback) Options both domestic and international.

The Thinkpad / Lenovo Power Manager is a great Windows tool for power shaping and I've personally garnered three and nearly five years of usage from my Thinkpad batteries and with frequent daily usage.

[image]
Using third party aftermarket replacement batteries is an excellent option despite the manufacturer warnings to use only genunine parts. Rely on user reviews such as the [ones at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074TZK2GP) to determine which alternative manufacturer is best for you.

Lenovo provides [an excellent tip sheet on battery usage and longevity](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht069687) and it is better than most other makers in my opinion:

[image]